# Event for when a payment is made

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal-webhooks

I am trying to do an integration with Paypal webhooks.

This integration needs to send an http request when a payment is made.

Example:

- Sandbox account sends $100 to another sandbox account.
- The webhook needs to send the transaction data.
- I receive the data and can manipulate it

But currently the webhook is not fully triggered, not even I receive the error or any other kind of event in the event history of paypal.

Currently my webserver is listening for **all** events, but no event is triggered when I send money.

Currently my webserver is listening for **all** events, but no event is triggered when I send money.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal Webhooks are only sent for events associated with a REST App.

In the Live environment (not Sandbox), "NVP/SOAP" webhooks can also be registered, which may or may not produce some account-level events you are interested in.

Apart from what was just described, there are no other sources of PayPal Webhooks.